# Why do I get a 401 error when using Ruby to execute a Google Fusion Tables API command?

Tags: ruby, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-api-client, google-api-ruby-client

I'm using the Ruby gem 'google-api-client', and I make sure to add in all my credentials, but for some reason, I keep getting a 401 error from Google.

Here's my code:

```
['google/api_client','json'].each{|g| require g}

client_secrets = File.open('client_secrets.json','r').read # My client secrets are stored in this .JSON file
client_secrets_hsh = JSON.parse(client_secrets)

client = Google::APIClient.new
client.authorization.client_id = client_secrets_hsh['installed']['client_id']
client.authorization.client_secret = client_secrets_hsh['installed']['client_secret']
client.authorization.redirect_uri = client_secrets_hsh['installed']['redirect_uris'][0]
client.authorization.access_token = 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN'
client.authorization.username = 'MY_USER_NAME@gmail.com'
client.authorization.password = 'MY_GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD'
client.authorization.scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables'

request_body = ''
headers = []
headers << ['Content-Type','application/json']

api = client.discovered_api('fusiontables','v1')

result = client.execute(
    :api_method => api.to_h['fusiontables.table.list'],
    :parameters => {'maxResults' => 1000},
    :merged_body => request_body,
    :headers => headers
)

puts result.response.body
```

And here's the response I get back from the `puts results.response.body` line:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Username and password should not be supplied. Try dropping those to start. You only need the access token in order to make API calls. Which, incidentally, I'm not sure where you got that from. Usually you'd need to make a call to `fetch_access_token!` somewhere. It's normally not something you set via an accessor. There are advanced cases where you would – but you're probably not one of them.